# Zkteco SDK Function to Change User Status

Tags: vb.net, sdk, biometrics, zkteco

I have worked with ZKTECO Biometric machines before but now i need an extra feature which i didn't find in existing ZKTECO SDK. Is there any extension in SDK so that i enable or disable user from a machine while the information of user is still in the machine.So that it's status could be changed any time. I need this for an access control project where user privileges changes on daily basis and admin can't afford to go and register an employee every time.

I found this sdk online which claims to do the trick but no luck.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1104538/Csharp-ZKTeco-Biometric-Device-Getting-Started

Answer (score 2):

After working for days on this i finally found the solution to this problem. What i did was to download all user templates to my local database and then with the help of SDK i added or removed a user from Machine by deleting the finger print templates of that particular user from machine and in case i want to allow it i uploaded the templates from my local database again.
It was a headache doing all this but i am sharing the code here

https://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?waid=266467&aid=1254373

Hope this would be helpful cause i haven't found anything relating to this available on the internet already.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the users are not supported by the Zk biometric machines. What you need to do is, delete the user from the machine. Before deleting make sure the user details (id, name, template) are stored in your database. Then whenever you want to enable the user, just push the user data to the machine back. This way you will achieve enable/disable features from your software.

Answer (score 0):

*Is there any extension in SDK so that i enable or disable user from a machine while the information of user is still in the machine.*

To enable/disable a user you can use:

```
VARIANT_BOOL EnableUser([in] long dwMachineNumber, [in] long dwEnrollNumber,
[in] long dwEMachineNumber, [in] long dwBackupNumber, [in] VARIANT_BOOL bFlag);
```

where the bFlag set to `true` means enabled and bFlag set to `false` means the user is disabled.

Comment: This code does work but after reading many of ZKTECO documentations it's cleared to me that this particular code changes the Admin user access whether the user i allowed to access control panel of Machine or not.